# How can we sum the values group by from file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sh

I have a file where I have student Roll no, Name, Subject, Obtain Marks and Total Marks data:

```
10 William English 80 100
10 William Math 50 100
10 William IT 60 100
11 John English 90 100
11 John Math 75 100
11 John IT 85 100
```

How can i get Group by sum (total obtained marks) of every student in shell Shell? I want this output:

```
William 190
John 250
```

i have tried this:

```
cat student.txt | awk '{sum += $14}END{print sum" "$1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 10
```

This is not working link group by sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With one `awk` command:

```
awk '{a[$2]+=$4} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
```

Output

```
William 190
John 250
```

If you want to sort the output, you can pipe to `sort`, e.g. descending by numerical second field:

```
awk '{a[$2]+=$4} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file | sort -rnk2
```

or ascending by student name:

```
awk '{a[$2]+=$4} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file | sort
```

Comment: how can we do this without "awk"

Answer (score 2):

You need to use associative array in awk.

Try

```
awk '{ a[$2]=a[$2]+$4 } END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}'
```

`a[$2]=a[$2]+$4`  Create associate array with $2 as index and sum of values $4 as value

`END` <-- Process all records

`for (i in a) print i, a[i]` <-- Print index and value of array

Demo :

```
$awk '{ a[$2]=a[$2]+$4 } END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' temp.txt 
William 190
John 250
$cat temp.txt 
10 William English 80 100
10 William Math 50 100
10 William IT 60 100
11 John English 90 100
11 John Math 75 100
11 John IT 85 100
$
```